# How to manage a single form of data in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have a scenario where I want to let a user manage their Contact Info in Django.

Right now, I have a model that looks like this:

```
class ContactInfo(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', help_text='The contact phone number used on the website.', blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', help_text='The contact email address to use on the website.', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Contact Info"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Website Contact Info"
```

And what this does, is it creates a class named `ContactInfo` and the Django admin gives me the option to "Add" as many `ContactInfo` objects as I want.

**What I want, instead,** is a *single place* in the Django Admin to edit the **Only ContactInfo** object, where I can click on "Contact Info" and a form pops up with the ability to edit/save the contact info, and without the ability to "Add" a hundred "Contact" objects.

So far, my solution is simply disable the "Add" button in the Admin using the following:

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Disable the Add Button in the admin
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

That works, but this still requires me to go "two levels" deep in the Admin just to get to the form where I can edit the information.

**There must be a better way to manage this, can anyone provide me with some advice? I would appreciate it.**

**UPDATE:** The user @GwynBleidD suggested a combination of `list_editable` and removing `list_display_links`, which works nicely (thanks!) for small sets of data like contact info, because it lets me edit the data on the very next "click" in the admin (so I don't have to go "two levels deep" just to get to the data). But I am looking for a scalable solution that will cater nicely to small or large data sets.

Comment: Can't you use `list_editable` and remove`list_display_links`? If not, maybe replace list view with redirect?

Comment: @GwynBleidD, thanks for the suggestion. I have never used those options before, so I will look them up in the documentation and see if it's something that might work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @GwynBleidD, that is actually a handy trick, and it could work nicely if all I had to do was manage contact info, but if I were to apply this same idea to a data model that required a large textarea or multiple fields, then your suggestion won't carry over. Can you think of something that can be scalable to manage lots of fields on the data model? I will update my question to be more specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide every form field into separate row in database, so your model will have 3 fields: name of field, type of field and saved data (most probably in PostgreSQL `JSONField` or some sort of serialization in `TextField` for flexibility). You can lay out that fields so they will look like in detail view.

It will require some javascript that will switch form fields based on field type and serialize data when saving if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can just redirect user from list view to detail view of first element on list. It won't even need to modify anything in admin, just create separate view that will redirect user to page and register in on url that will be normally occupied by list view. Remember that your view must be registered in `urls.py` before django admin.

Comment: All of these suggestions seem like great options. I will try them out and come back to mark one of these as the correct answer after a little experimentation. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is to create totally custom view that will just be styled as admin site or to modify `ModelAdmin` so it will meet your requirements.